# Can I adjust upvc door?

Tags: doors

This place I've moved into has a door that rubs each time, it seems the frame isnt square.

Is there a way to adjust the UPVC hinges to compensate?

[image: the door hinge with the door open]

[image: the door hinge with the door closed]

Comment: Is this a place you own or rent? If you're renting, call maintenance / the landlord.

Answer (score 1):

There are 3 types of UPVC hinges.

[image]

You seem to have the Butt Type.

While the other 2 are adjustable the Butt Hinge is limited to none.

Remove the cap on top and bottom of the hinge to find out if there is a adjustment screw inside.

[image: butt hinge]

Comment: Are you sure that the hex-head bolt you've highlighted from the OP's pic isn't the adjustment itself? It appears to have 3 marks on it, and there's one on the hinge. Looks like giving that bolt a little turn may cause adjustment of the hinge. OTOH, it might just loosen the hing from the frame...

Comment: Thanks. I'll have a go of this at the weekend. I appreciate the help and input from you all.